# Geometry nodes - Curve Array with Constant Step

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I want to make a Curve Array with constant 0 step, like on the gif.
For now, i guess, in geometry nodes, if you want to do an array, you should use setup below, but it provides non constant step.

(Of course we are talking about several **curved** splines in a curve, not just a straight line in this task)

[image]

Simple setup, that I'm using:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Using **Simple Mesh Line** node with **Sample Curve node**, due to specific behavior of **Mesh Line Node** we are able to "create" instances with constant step

[image]

So we need just to Sample Position from that Mesh Line and Set those Position to the original Curve

[image]

Also working with many curves thanks to All Curves Radio button on the **Sample Curve NOde**
[image]

Comment: Hi Bicukow, can you share the node setup for this please, the above one is not working, or the blend file if you will

Answer (score 3):

`Curve to Points` and `Resample Curve` nodes at *Length* mode will round the provided value down so there's no small piece of curve left at the end. From [the user manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/curve_to_points.html#properties):

> **Length:** Sample each spline by splitting it into segments with specified length. **The length will be rounded down** so that a whole number of samples will fit in each input spline. To counteract jumping when the length of the spline changes, the Trim Curve node can be used with a multiple of this length.

Here's a setup where you can get the `Curve Length`, `Divide` that by the desired length (the length of your instances) and `Round` down the result to see how many instances would fit the curve we have. Then you `Trim Curve` to the exact length before resampling it:

[image]

This should work, but it seems to fail at some particular values. I'm not sure why that is—if I'm missing something or if it's a bug:

[image]

Using a `Subdivide Curve` instead of `Curve to Mesh` or `Resample Curve` seems to work without any hitches, if that suits you:

[image]

Comment: I didn't get it: why are the cubes scaling on your example?

Comment: and it's also not working.. sorry, but thanks for your attention

Comment: @Bicukow Because I'm using the dividing value to also size the cubes, if you simply move the endpoint of the curve to lengthen it, cubes won't scale. I'll change the gif when I find the time if that's confusing.

Comment: @Bicukow What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I mean it's not working like on my first gif

Comment: I realy think this task should be done with curve sample node, but i do not how..
because we should not use the original geometry as points for instansing

Comment: @Bicukow Can you show me how it's not working? What does it do? Why do you think we shouldn't use the original for instancing?

Comment: Can you please update your gif? The Cubes are still scaling