# How to make a object array and follow along a drawn curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, instances

[image]

I have a central object here (call it A) and I want to draw a curve and have the object array as well as follow the curve path.

I want to be able to draw curves in realtime or use grease pencil and have the objects create as I make these lines or curves in my viewport.

Edit: I want to create a pattern such that when I am creating or extruding the curve horizontally or vertically, the nodesetup should array along the curve, but if I try to make the curve go diagonal, the array should appear in like a arrow head shape, something like this:

[image]

Comment: There's a tutorial by Joey Carlino of a [footstep generator](https://youtu.be/T_ZzO86dBIA) using geometry nodes which you might be able to adapt for your use. You could probably use your object instead of the plane that he uses for the footstep image.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285278/geometry-nodes-curve-array-with-constant-step https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251794/geometry-nodes-array-on-a-curve https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296050/geometry-nodes-curve-deform-array-on-multiple-splines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/lamp-posts-correctly-oriented-instances-on-a-3d-curve/

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have already been asked in various forms over time and already has a multiple answers, but you never acknowledged any of the existing posts. We are not sure if you aware of them but none of the described techniques fulfil your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Comment: Hey @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, yeah I didn't know about these posts, thanks! I'll go over all of them. My question differs because I want a pixel kind of effect, not a simple array and curve where if I create a curve straight it will only array once but if I array it diagonally it should create two adjacent objects (like a arrow head) following the curve.

Comment: Could you edit those det into your question and clarify what you are trying to achieve? You can then vote to reopen so it is queued up for review

Comment: it's still unclear what you want exactly